# How to change an objects key values to lowerCase for sorting

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating a custom sorting method in Angular that takes as a parameter a name of type string. In the .html file, whenever a user clicks on the arrows lets say for example next to 'UserName', the UserName is passed in as an argument to my sorting method. I want my method to be case-insensitive and can't seem to figure out a way to access and change the array of objects key values. Using the above example of 'UserName', I want to access the objects key name 'UserName', and make the value lower case before sorting. That way my sorting method will work properly. Keep in mind, my data is inside an array that contains objects of user info. I am using bracket notation also to keep it dynamic; for example in my method you will see a[name] < b[name] where [name] is equal to whatever the user clicks on.

My .TS FILE

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
})
export class UsersComponent extends ComponentCanDeactivate implements OnDestroy {
  entries: User[] = []; isAscendingOrder=false; isFaSort=true; sortByParam='';
  faEdit=faEdit; faTrash=faTrash; faCaretSquareDown=faCaretSquareDown; faCaretSquareUp=faCaretSquareUp; faSort=faSort;
  @ViewChild('addUserForm') formValues;

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private globals: GlobalsService, private modalService: NgbModal) {
    super(); this.load();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() { try { this.modalService.dismissAll(); } catch(err) { console.log(err); } }

  canDeactivate(): boolean { return !this.modalService.hasOpenModals();}

  load(){
    this.userService.getAllUsers(r => {
      if (r) {
        this.entries = r; this.getValues(this.entries)
      } else {
        this.globals.toastr.error('Error getting users');
      }
    });
  }



  switchIcon() {
    if(this.isFaSort) {
      return faSort;
    } else {
      return this.isAscendingOrder? faCaretSquareUp:faCaretSquareDown;
    }
  }

  getValues(userArray: User[]) {
    userArray.forEach(e=> {
      const result = Object.entries(e).map(([k,v]) => {
        e.UserName = v.toLowerCase();
      })
      console.log(result);
    });

  }

  sortByField(name:string) {

    this.isFaSort = false;
    if(this.sortByParam == name) {
      this.isAscendingOrder= !this.isAscendingOrder;
    } else {
      this.sortByParam = name;
      this.isAscendingOrder = true;
    }




    if(this.isAscendingOrder) {
        return this.entries.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[name] < b[name])
          return -1;
        if (a[name] > b[name])
          return 1;
        return 0;
        });
      } else {
      return this.entries.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[name] < b[name])
          return 1;
        if (a[name] > b[name])
          return -1;
        return 0;
      });
    }
  }
```

You can see in my .ts file I am trying to find out a way to change the objects key value.

.HTML file

```
<div class="table-overflow-container">
                <table class='table table-bordered table-fixed-header table-striped table-narrow table-hover'>
                    <thead class="my-thead">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="clickable" (click)="sortByField('UserName')">User name<fa-icon style="float: right;"  [icon]="switchIcon()">
                            </fa-icon>
                            </td>
                            <td class="clickable" (click)="sortByField('Email')">Email<fa-icon style="float: right;"  [icon]="switchIcon()">
                            </fa-icon></td>
                            <td>Roles</td>
                            <td class="clickable">Disabled<fa-icon style="float: right;"  [icon]="switchIcon()">
                            </fa-icon></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let u of entries">
                            <td class="clickable" (click)="editUser(u.id)">{{u.UserName}}</td>
                            <td class="clickable" (click)="editUser(u.id)">{{u.Email}}</td>
                            <td class="clickable" (click)="editUser(u.id)">{{ getRoleNames(u.UserRoles) }}</td>
                            <td class="clickable" (click)="editUser(u.id)">{{u.Disabled==0?"No":"Yes"}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add toLowerCase() modifier. if a[name] could be something not string, then a[name].toString().toLowerCase()

```
if(this.isAscendingOrder) {
    return this.entries.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[name].toLowerCase() < b[name].toLowerCase())
      return -1;
    if (a[name].toLowerCase() > b[name].toLowerCase())
      return 1;
    return 0;
    });
  } else {
  return this.entries.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[name].toLowerCase() < b[name].toLowerCase())
      return 1;
    if (a[name].toLowerCase() > b[name].toLowerCase())
      return -1;
    return 0;
  });
}
```

Comment: wow.. I was pretty sure I was adding the toLowerCase method and it was telling me constantly it could not.. but idk it works now! This is what I was looking for based on my code so will be the accepted answer although I like the approach suggested above to organize my code better.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it slightly more organized like this:

```
sortByField(name:string) {

    this.isFaSort = false;
    if(this.sortByParam == name) {
      this.isAscendingOrder= !this.isAscendingOrder;
    } else {
      this.sortByParam = name;
      this.isAscendingOrder = true;
    }

    function getLowerCaseEntry(a, b) {
        return a[b].toLowerCase();
    }

    function compareStr(a ,b, asc) {
        return asc ? a.localeCompare(b) : b.localeCompare(a);
    }

    this.entries.sort((x,y) => compareStr(getLowerCaseEntry(x, name), getLowerCaseEntry(y, name), this.isAscendingOrder));
}
```